# Почему не создается архив на сервере?

Tags: php, zip, ziparchive

Пытаюсь добавить в архив файлы из указанной директории с помощью стандартного класса ZipArchive, однако архив не создается. Что я делаю не так? Гугление ничего не дало, везде код практически одинаковый.

```
 $pathdir='/var/www/files/other/osvega/test/';
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 if ($zip -> open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
 {
     $dir = opendir( $pathdir );
     while( $d = readdir( $dir ) ){
        echo "Добавляем в архив файл ".$d." размером ".filesize( $pathdir.$d 
        )."<br />";
        $zip -> addFile( $pathdir.$d, $d);          
     }
     $zip -> close();
     echo 'Файлы добавлены в архив';
 }
 else echo 'Ошибка!';
```

Comment: Включите вывод ошибок в php и читайте логи

Comment: phpinfo() и смотрите включен ли у вас модуль ZIP